# How to remember an FTP account in Cyberduck Mac FTP Client?

Tags: ftp, mac, cyberduck

I had a hard time to enter all the credentials to log in to my FTP account. After closing the app, Cyberduck doesn't offer me these credentials anymore. Even though I checked that the password shall be stored in the Keychain.

How would I persist these details so I would not have to look up those credentials every time?

Comment: Read the help/manual and use search engines before to ask!

Comment: Voted to move to superuser. (I prefer it when someone votes down/close something of mine that they leave a reason out of courtesy and it helps new users understand the site rules regarding content better.)

Answer (score 7):

Did you try to add a bookmarks ? (command-shift-b)